# Why do My shortcut icons change to a robot?

Tags: app-icons

I have a rooted Vodafone VF685, running Kitkat 4.4.2 with ADW Launcher. I'm having trouble with my shortcut icons. They keep changing at random to the green Android robot. The apps still launch when I tap the robot, but it's annoying.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I cannot find /system on local or SD card, and root browsing is enabled.

Comment: Icons are stored with apk itself. system apps apk's are stored in /system/app and user apps( from playstore ) are stored apk's at /data/app

Comment: which file manager you are using?

Comment: ES File Explorer. Right now my WhatsApp icon is a robot and I cannot even find the WhatsApp folder nader /Android/Data...yet, all my chats and media show  in WhatsApp. Just now 2 More icons turned to a robot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. I opened ES Task Manager again, killed all apps and cleared the cache. Icons back to normal. I found the idea here: [*lcons Broken*](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-samsung-galaxy-nexus/258918-icons-broken.html)

Thank you Rahul for assisting.

Answer (score 3):

For me this worked: deleting the shortcut and adding another back onto the homescreen. :)